# My segue goes too far back

Tags: ios, swift

[This is how my story board currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL1nK.png)

When I click the buttons on the view with the buttons placed vertically, I can open up the correct corresponding view, however, when I unwind back I end up going all the way back to the sign in page, not the page with the buttons. I have the unwind segue in the right place, just don't know why it's going that far back.

This is the code for the view controller with the buttons

```
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var clubButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var announcemnetsButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var eventButton: UIButton!

var transition = QZCircleSegue()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    menuButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButton.frame.size.width / 2
    clubButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButton.frame.size.width / 2
    announcemnetsButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButton.frame.size.width / 2
    eventButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButton.frame.size.width / 2

    menuButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    clubButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    announcemnetsButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    eventButton.layer.masksToBounds = true

}
override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    return true;

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "NewVC") {
        self.transition.animationChild = menuButton
        self.transition.animationColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if (segue.identifier == "ClubVC") {
        self.transition.animationChild = clubButton
        self.transition.animationColor = UIColor(red: 81/255, green: 172/255, blue: 246/255, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if (segue.identifier == "AnnouncementVC") {
        self.transition.animationChild = announcemnetsButton
        self.transition.animationColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 179/255, blue: 109/255, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if segue.identifier == "EventVC" {
        self.transition.animationChild = eventButton
        self.transition.animationColor = UIColor(red: 63/255, green: 255/255, blue: 176/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    let toViewController = segue.destination as! NewViewController
    /* Set both, the origin and destination to your transition manager*/
    self.transition.fromViewController = self
    self.transition.toViewController = toViewController
    /* Add the transition manager to your transitioningDelegate View Controller*/
    toViewController.transitioningDelegate = transition
}

/* Specify the destination view controller to enable the unwind segue*/
@IBAction func unwindToMainViewController (sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}
}

Comment: post your code, especially the unwind one with view controller connection in storyboard

Comment: I just posted my code

Comment: While the code looks all right, it is difficult to say what is going on without seeing the storyboard connections. You can also try to isolate the problem by reducing the functionality of prepare().

Comment: code is correct why don't you just dismiss Controller instead of unwind Segue ?

Answer (score 1):

The comment that iOS made is right on the money.  Just because you used a segue to get to a view controller doesn't mean you have to use one to leave.  Assuming you want to go back to the view controller you were just displaying, there are a couple of possibilities.  What you want to do is pop the current view controller off the stack. If you're using a navigation controller (most likely you are), then this is how to do that:

```
 self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You might be able to simplify it to this:

```
 dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

since view controllers have a self.dismiss() method.  Give it a try and let me know whether this works for you.

Comment: could you clarify your answer?  Maybe this makes perfect sense to the OP, but I don't think it's totally clear what you are saying.  Thanks!

Comment: a billion times!  Thank you, this makes total sense now!

Comment: So glad I could help. It's easy to get lost in the details.